# What's the word for the when you suck snot back up your nose?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

My mom and I say 'soup' like: "Why are you souping the snot back up your nose?" But I realise that this is not accurate. So what's the word?

Comment: My mom always said “snert.” I thought that was the technical term until a few days ago!

Answer (score 4):

Although there is no exact fit for this, the term most used by medical officials is 'Snorting'.

Answer (score 4):

The words I would use is either **sniff** or **sniffle** (depending on how hard or often it's done), which are defined respectively as:

> Draw up air audibly through the nose to detect a smell, to stop it running, or to express contempt.
>   <sub>Sniff—[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sniff)</sub>

> Sniff slightly or repeatedly, typically because of a cold or fit of crying.
>   <sub>Sniffle—[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sniffle)</sub>

Comment: Of course, to sniff. Everyone seems to be unaware of the most obvious here. Let's not forget that snuffle also works. :)

Answer (score 2):

“To snort” is the most commonly used phrase

Comment: Welcome to ELU, please consider adding sources to support your answers.

Comment: Please be sure to look at all existing answers before posting. Somebody has already suggested this.

Answer (score 0):

*Insufflate* means 'breathe in, blow in' with *in* being important because there is exsufflate for *out*.

Dictionary.com has

> **Insufflate** - verb (used with object), insufflated, insufflating.
>   1. to blow or breathe (something) in.
>   2. Medicine/Medical. to blow (air or a medicinal substance) into some opening or upon some part of the body.

I don't believe there is a single word for *snot* that isn't a bit 'slangy' sounding so *nasal mucus* is as scientific a term as I can think of.

That means you'd be performing *nasal mucus insufflation* and your mother might ask *Why are you insufflating nasal mucus?*

---

<sub>Dictionary.com, "insufflate," in Dictionary.com Unabridged. Source location: Random House, Inc. http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/insufflate. Available: http://dictionary.reference.com. Accessed: January 07, 2015.</sub>

Comment: That might be medical but nothing else.